# MagpieRSS: Failed to fetch error

Tags: php, rss, magpie

When my script parses an RSS feed from my local Apache server, it parses fine but when I upload script to the remote hosting server it gives the error:

> Warning: Magpie RSS: Failed to fetch (url) and cache is off in magpierss-0.6/rss_fetch.inc
>
> on line 231.

I have searched for possible answers and any suggestions are around enabling and changing cache lifetime. I think that is not the problem - it looks like the problem is with remote hosting Apache server or denied access to my host.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that magpie can open the rss url. Usually with curl being enabled or allow_url_fopen on your server. Also make sure that magpie is able/allowed/permitted to create caching files (if any)

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a bad url, the server is busy or not having remote file access allowed in your host.

$errormsg = "Failed to fetch $url "; in source indicative of problem getting to host.

Try checking access from the remote host - if you have ssh & curl enabled just do 
curl (url)

Comment: I have tried with curl functions from script and reaturns empty screen.

Comment: I have tried fith curl functions from php script and returs white screen.

The thing is that our site is rss news agregator, and parses over 100 rss feeds, and this is the first time this problem apears, only with feeds form certan source. 

I think that they don't give access to our site to parse their feeds, and if why from my local machine feeds are parsed fine.

Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried using curl -v to see exactly what is happening

Comment: We will contact them  directly to see if they are blocking our server.